# PreferenceFragment with support library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-support-library

I'm developing an app where I've been using the support library fragments throughout and I stumbled upon this problem where I can't seem to add a `PreferencesFragment` (for the settings) using this library?

I've found some suggestions to use `v7 PreferenceFragmentCompat`, however looks like for some reason I can't add the `v7` support library to my build path, therefore I can't locate the `PreferenceFragmentCompat`...

I've tried rewriting the code to use regular fragments  instead of the ones in support library, but I had some issues with that too

In case you're wondering, I'm developing with support library because, while reading The Big Nerd Ranch book on android programming, somewhere early on they advise always using support library for fragments.

Any suggestions on the workarounds, or should I just try to switch to non-support version?

Here are the dependencies from my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: why you can't add support library to your build path?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?  If you're using Android Studio show your build.gradle dependencies....

Comment: here's my gradle dependencies dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
@DanielNugent

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The appcompat v7 library actually uses the v4 support library, so you need to explicitly import the v7 support library components that you need.

In your case, you just need to add  `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'`  to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Then this will work:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.view.View;

public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    public MyPreferenceFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings_pref);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did have an issue in the gradle itself, I wasn't paying attention thinking adding the dependencies in project structure will automatically config the gradle file.

Comment: You sir, saved my day.

Comment: You should place `addPreferencesFromResource` in [onCreatePreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#onCreatePreferences(android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)): "Called during `onCreate(Bundle)` to supply the preferences for this fragment. Subclasses are expected to call `setPreferenceScreen(PreferenceScreen)` either directly or via helper methods such as `addPreferencesFromResource(int)`."

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with androidx use;

```
 implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0"
 implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The gradle dependency for support library preference fragment is:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:28.0.0'
```